LSTM migration from Tensorflow to PyTorch. Different output for same weights and inputs?
I have a task to migrate tensorflow(1.15) model with a LSTM layer to a Pytorch model. I am trying to migrate the weights from the tesnorflow model to the pytorch model. However, even after migrating the weights the output from tensorflow and pytorch are differet.
// Tensorflow model
def lstm_model(x):
    forward_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(2)
    backward_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(2)
    #  ([batch_size, max_time, cell_fw.output_size],  [batch_size, max_time, cell_bw.output_size])
    encoder_outputs,_ = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(
            forward_cell,
            backward_cell,
            x,
            dtype=tf.float32
        )
    encoder_outputs = tf.concat(encoder_outputs, axis=2)
    return encoder_outputs

// Weight migration
def get_pytorch_lstm_weights_from_tensorflow(kernel, bias, INPUT_SIZE, HIDDEN_SIZE):
    def reorder_lstm_weights(w):
        return np.transpose(w)

    w_ih = nn.Parameter(reorder_lstm_weights(torch.tensor((kernel[:INPUT_SIZE]))))
    w_hh = nn.Parameter(reorder_lstm_weights(torch.tensor((kernel[INPUT_SIZE:]))))
    if bias is not None:
        alpha = 0.5
        b_ih = nn.Parameter(reorder_lstm_weights(torch.tensor((alpha * bias[:INPUT_SIZE]))))
        b_hh = nn.Parameter(reorder_lstm_weights(torch.tensor((1-alpha) * bias[:INPUT_SIZE])))
    else:
        b_ih = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(4 * HIDDEN_SIZE))
        b_hh = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(4 * HIDDEN_SIZE))

    return w_ih, w_hh, b_ih, b_hh

amp_factor = 2
bi_lstm_window_size  = 42
num_classes =2

# input_shape = (1,10, 512)

# Create the constant tensor
random_array = np.random.rand(1, 1, 1)
x = tf.convert_to_tensor(random_array, dtype=tf.float32)

tf_lstm_model = lstm_model(x)
// PyTorch model
model = nn.LSTM(input_size=1, hidden_size=2, bidirectional=True, batch_first=True)
        
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    print("Final")
    print("Input", x.shape)
    outputcnn = sess.run(tf_lstm_model)
    outputcnn = np.array(outputcnn)
    vars = sess.graph.get_collection('trainable_variables')

    weights = {}
    for v in vars:
        weights[v.name] = sess.run(v)  # retrieve the value from the tf backend
    weights_list = [(k, v) for k, v in weights.items()]
    for ele in weights_list:
        print(ele[0], ele[1].shape)

    with torch.no_grad():
      pt_model_params = list(model.named_parameters())
      n_tf = 0
      n_pt = 0
      while n_tf<len(weights_list):
            pt_name, pt_param = pt_model_params[n_pt]
            tf_name, tf_param = weights_list[n_tf]
            if "lstm" in tf_name:
                  kernel = tf_param
                  _, bias = weights_list[n_tf+1]
                  # from input kernel get the second dimension of shape
                  input_size = pt_model_params[n_pt][1].size()[1]
                  # from hidden kernel get the second dimension of shape
                  hidden_size = pt_model_params[n_pt+1][1].size()[1]
                  w_ih, w_hh, b_ih, b_hh = get_pytorch_lstm_weights_from_tensorflow(tf_param, bias, input_size, hidden_size)
                  # print(torch.tensor(w_ih).size(), torch.tensor(w_hh).size(), torch.tensor(b_ih).size(), torch.tensor(b_hh).size())
                  to_copy_params = [w_ih, w_hh, b_ih, b_hh]
                  for i in range(4):
                       pt_model_params[n_pt+i][1].copy_(torch.tensor(to_copy_params[i], requires_grad=True, dtype=pt_param.dtype))
                  n_pt=n_pt+4
                  n_tf=n_tf+2
                  continue

      vars = sess.graph.get_collection('trainable_variables')
      
      x_list = x.eval()
      x_np = np.array(x_list)
      # x_np= np.transpose(x_list, (0, 3, 1, 2)).copy()
      x_pt = torch.tensor(x_np, dtype=torch.float32)

      full_output, last_output= model(x_pt)
      pt_layer_output = full_output.detach().numpy()
      
      print("Output pt", full_output.shape)
      print("Output TF", outputcnn.shape)

      print(np.abs(outputcnn-pt_layer_output).max())
      # print("Close?", np.allclose(tf_output_transposed, pt_layer_output, atol=1e-07))
      print("Output pt", full_output)
      print("Output TF", outputcnn)

Output received
Output Pytorch tensor([[[-0.0313, -0.0366,  0.1290, -0.0091]]])
Output Tensorflow [[[-0.15243384  0.03754938 -0.1181007   0.09257261]]]

Can someone please suggest why the outputs are different?
